# Handle multiple accounts in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I am working on a react JS web app that will allow users to be logged into multiple accounts at once. it will be similar to how Google allows you to be logged in with multiple accounts.

My question is what is the best way to keep track of what user is being used in each tab? How would I ensure that the current account being used gets passed to a new tab if a user clicked a link with “open in new tab”?

Comment: Couldn't you just use Session Storage?

Comment: I was looking at that but the issue is I need something that is passed for one page to another when a link is used, but isn’t present if a new tab is opened. I didn’t think session storage could do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out how google includes the user in their links - the `u/0`, `u/1`, `u/2`. This might set you on the right path. I'd do this, then get that param from the URL then play with session storage or cookies as required.

[image: google user tracking]

---

**Edits after comment discussion**

I've created a code sandbox for you to see how you can achieve this with react-router-dom.

https://codesandbox.io/s/small-platform-jlwpg

Have a look through it, some notable items to keep an eye on are:

1. The nesting of the routers with the `userId` param:

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
  <Route exact path="/mail" element={<Mail />}>
    <Route path=":userId" element={<Mailbox />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

2. The use of `<Outlet/>` in `Mail.jsx`. Without this, Mail won't render that sub-route.
3. The use of the `useParams` hook in `Mailbox.jsx`

```
const { userId } = useParams();
```

Comment: I saw that and was also thinking may making a /:ID/ as the root of all my routes. Wasn’t sure if that was the best way to do it though.

Comment: Yeah the google auth system is pretty sophisticated but after playing with firebase auth enough, I believe it is more or less working on this principle

Comment: So far I can’t find anything that would suggest how to create a ‘/:id/’ root route and all the rest of the routes as a sub route. Will react router even do that? Any idea where to look?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a code sandbox to help you set up react-router-dom with subroutes.

Comment: Took a look at your sandbox, but it doesn't seem to address sub routes below the ID. For example on Google Drive you have might see "drive.google.com/u/1/folder/filename". I was able to figure out how to do the ID as the end item, but I can't seem to figure out to have the ID within the route with other routes below it.

Comment: The trick is to keep nesting in that Routes component. Have a look in the sandbox now, I just added another nested route to represent a folder. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I think something might have gone wrong in the code. When you get to the nested URL the ID gets lost, instead of "Mailbox 1" the title becomes "Mailbox some-folder" as it thinks that "some-folder" is the UserID.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238876/discussion-between-steve-and-mav2287).